# Simple random query from database

Tags: php, mysql, random

I currently have an ads listing site on which there are 3 ordering filters. By default, the ads are sorted with the following line:

```
    $this->setState('filter_order', $app->getUserStateFromRequest('com_adsman.filter_order','filter_order', "start_date"));
```

When I change the start_date to another column name, it sorts by that column by default, so I know that's where the change needs to be done. Now, how would I go about displaying random results, based on the above piece of code?

Thanks!

Edit: Here is where the actual query is called.

```
            $Orderings[]    = "`a`.$filter_order $filter_order_Dir";
    $Orderings[]    = "`a`.`id` $filter_order_Dir ";        

$query = " SELECT ".implode(",",$SelectCols)." \r\n ".

     " FROM `#__ads` AS `a` \r\n".

     implode(" \r\n ",$JoinList)."\r\n".

     $where."\r\n".

     " GROUP BY `a`.`id` ".

     " ORDER BY ".implode(",",$Orderings)." \r\n ";
```

I'm thinking of using something like

$rand = rand(.implode(",",$SelectCols));

and changing $filter_order to $rand..I know this is not going to work tho, wrong syntax and wrong everything, this is where I need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, since the query is created somewhere else, and only filled with the parameters coming from this line ... you can't just change this line ...

find the actual query ... append a new column like "rand() as random" and change "start_date" to "random" in this line ...

//edit:

```
$query = " SELECT ".implode(",",$SelectCols).",rand() as random \r\n ".
     " FROM `#__ads` AS `a` \r\n".
     implode(" \r\n ",$JoinList)."\r\n".
     $where."\r\n".
     " GROUP BY `a`.`id` ".
     " ORDER BY ".implode(",",$Orderings)." \r\n ";
```

should give you a random column named "random" (of course, if there is already a column with that name, that would be trouble ... so maybe choose a unique name instead of "random")

Comment: Thank you, I edited my original post with the query! Any ideas?

Comment: @Sherif ... there you go ... but even if i wouldn't go for tandu's approach because SQL-Like code should belong in the code that generates the query, not in the code that uses the generator, in this case it will be easier for you to take tandus solution, because you won't have to change something that you don't fully understand ...

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but for some reason it did not work! Is there somwhere I need to insert random? In the $Orderings array? Edit: Just re-read your post, changed the start_date line and still nothing :/

Comment: i guess $filter_order is parameter number 3 from your first-posted code line ... in that case rename random in the query to `a.random` since you put 'a.' in front of everything you pass into that function

Comment: To no avail :/ I changed random to a.random in your query, and renamed the start_date value to random. Am I mixing things up haha?

Comment: it's 2 AM here ... maybe i'm mixing up things too ... have a look at the order of elements in your orderings array ... maybe you order by id first? can you get the text of the query before it's executed?

Comment: I unfortunately can't see the file I'm modifying, when I try to reach it on the server I just get a page with restricted access. When I comment out the restricted access line on top of the page I get all sorts of other errors..I'm on Joomla and it won't let me access scripts directly, so I don't actually know in what order the array is used..any ideas to see it?

Comment: is there any logging facility?

Answer (score 0):

Use `"RAND()"` as the `ORDER BY` column.

Comment: Thank you, but how would that work? This would be the equivalent of writing ORDER BY 17548 .I'm thinking of using array_rand on all the column names of the db. Everytime the page would load, it would sort by a different column?

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` (and nothing else) will randomize the order of the columns.  It's a MySQL function.  This is commonly used to select random rows from MySQL.  `array_rand` is also an option, but if you are going to randomize, why order by anything in the query?

Comment: Thank you, this works actually, I was using .rand(). the php function. The problem however is that by removing the imploded array of $Orderings, I've lost the other sorting functionality. How would I go about using rand AND the implode array if that makes sense?

Comment: stay with your original query, and try using $this->setState('filter_order', $app->getUserStateFromRequest('com_adsman.filter_order','filter_order', "RAND()")); ... maybe not clean, but easy enough ...